# Error creating DB2 Foreign Key

Tags: sql, db2

Table1:

```
Column    Primary Key    Generated
COL1      *              *
COL2      *
COL3      *
COL4
```

Table2:

```
Column   Primary Key    Generated
CCOL1
CCOL2
```

`CCOL1` in `Table2` is reference to `COL1` in `Table1`. I want to create foreign key for CCOL1 in Table2

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE2
  ADD CONSTRAINT CCOL1_FK
    FOREIGN KEY (CCOL1)
        REFERENCES TABLE1(COL1)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

Then getting this error message:

> A column list specified in the references clause of constraint
>       "CCOL1_FK" does not identify a unique constraint of the parent
>       table or nickname "TABLE1".. SQLCODE=-573, SQLSTATE=42890, DRIVER=4.18.60

It's clear but how do I connect `CCOL1` to `COL1`? I want restrict deletions from `TABLE1` if there is still `CCOL1` used in `TABLE2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foreign key normally can be referenced by unique key. But in your case, you must be having duplicate values in table1 - COL1 field. Make it as a unique field or try referencing with other unique key in table 1. Problem will be solved

Comment: Well so then what other constrain can I use? In other words I want COL1, COL2 and COL3 be unique in TABLE1(each column has only unique value). Or even COL1 is not unique I want to restrict TABLE2 CCOL1 to have values from COL1 TABLE1 only

Comment: In table 1 what is the primary key? Is it composite primary key including col1, col2 and col3 ?

Comment: If so, you can't reference part of a primary key with foreign key constraint.It should be either all three columns must be referenced in table 2 together or otherwise you should have only one column as primary key in table 1. Something like - ADD CONSTRAINT CCOL1_FK
    FOREIGN KEY (CCOL1,CCOL2,CCOL3)
        REFERENCES TABLE1(COL1,COL2,COL3)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT

Comment: Thank you. That explains